# Simple JUnit test not working

Tags: java, junit, bluej

We are currently learning JUnit testing in our programming class. Our task was to write a method that calculates the sum of the int values in an array:

```
public class PIArrays
{
    public int sum(final int[] array) {
        int sum = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            sum += array[i];
        }
        return sum; 
    }

}
```

Then we are supposed to write a test with the help of BlueJ's tools.

```
public void testSum()
{
    PIArrays pIArrays1 = new PIArrays();
    assertEquals(3, pIArrays1.sum({1,2}));
}
```

The sum method works just fine, however, the test results in this error message:

```
"illegal start of expression"
```

What exactly am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

*public class PIArraysTest* is wrong it's actually *public class PIArrays*. I copied the wrong line.

The error happens in my testing class: *public class PIArraysTest* in this line:

```
assertEquals(3, pIArrays1.sum({1,2}));
```

with this part:

```
({1,2})
```

beeing highlighted

Comment: You named your class `PIArraysTest` and you reference it as `PIArrays`? That does not sounds right. Try using `PIArraysTest pIArrays1 = new PIArraysTest();` in your test code. Also, please elaborate more about the error. Which line which class? This cant be the only information right?

Comment: `pIArrays1.sum({1,2})` -> `pIArrays1.sum(new int[]{1,2})`

Comment: Thanks for editing your question. This makes it a lot more clear what exactly you are asking. Keep this in mind while asking other questions on SO next time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`{1, 2}` as `int[]` is not a valid parameter. Use `new int[]{1, 2}` instead.

```
assertEquals(3, pIArrays1.sum(new int[]{1,2}));
```

Comment: This worked! Just one question. I did this in BlueJ with right clicking *create test class* and *create test method* and so on. Is it normal that BlueJ sometimes messes stuff like this up?

Comment: You mean the classes naming? Yes, it's quite possible that BlueJ appends suffix "Test" to your test class or stuff like that. I've never worked with BlueJ before actually. Glad to help you"